# add a zero after regex each lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like following:

```
ABCCC
4,322,469
FSFFSDF
4,322,000
GFGFGBFG
444,567
ABCFD
DFGHJKK
00000
```

Now I want to add zero after consecutive lines that start with a character like following:

```
ABCCC
4,322,469
FSFFSDF
4,322,000
GFGFGBFG
444,567
ABCFD
0
DFGHJKK
0
00000
```

following regex can select consecutive lines that start with a character:

```
^[A-Za-z].*\R([A-Za-z].*)$
```

I tried following regex but not working for me:

```
Find: ^[A-Za-z].*\R([A-Za-z].*)$  
Replace: \0\n0
```

where is my regex problem?

Comment: Your question is unclear, what are the rules to add a newline and a 0 ?

Comment: I don't know about notepad-xx and I'm *really not a friend* of microsoft as such and in general.  From what I have seen as implementations of regexp syntax, does "\0" denote "0" or rather the character with hex value 0? Have a lazy try on "0\n0", without the first backslash. Doesn't cost much time. And please tell me it it worked.

Comment: @GyroGearloose I tried but it replaced my lines with 0!

Comment: Where you say "start with a character" I believe you mean "start with a letter". The line `"444,567"` does not start with a letter so why have you inserted the line `"0"` after the line `"ABCFD"`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland because 0 lines removed by a mistakes! I should add it again to my list

Comment: In Linux, for most kinds of regexps, there is some symbol that reproduces the matched regexp. For our conversation, call it XXX (sure it isn't) and then tray "XXX\n0", with  XXX replaced appropriately. Doesn't sound like a severe problem, but I don't know the symbols used.

Comment: Why do you add `0` between `DFGHJKK` and `00000`?

Comment: @sln good but why you add POP to my list!?

Comment: @Toto From `ABCFD, DFGHJKK` to `ABCFD, 0, DFGHJKK, 0` what was unclear about this that prompted you to say it's unclear and vote to close this ? The solution is now hidden from the public. Sad but business as usual.

Comment: @sln: Explain why there is a `0` added after `DFGHJKK` but not after `ABCCC`

Comment: @Toto So like the difference between `ABCCC, 4,322,469` and `ABCFD, DFGHJKK` appears to be a _`block`_ of, being 2 or more, consecutive alpha starting lines. Otherwise if the single line is the minimum, it would be this simple regex `(?m)^[A-Za-z].*\R\K` https://regex101.com/r/Mrdt96/1

Comment: @sln: My question is: why is there a `0` added after `DFGHJKK`?

Comment: @Toto That's been explained 2 times to you: `ABCFD \n DFGHJKK` -> `ABCFD \n 0 \n DFGHJKK \n 0` My question is why do you keep asking, is it not clear to you why ? Do you see the pattern ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works in Notepad.

If you want to place a `0` after every one in a block of
consecutive Alpha lines, use the `\G` construct, and a look ahead.

`(?m)(?:^[A-Za-z].*\R(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<!\A)\G[A-Za-z].*\R)\K`

https://regex101.com/r/1inhnS/1

Overview

```
(?m)
(?:
   ^ 
   [A-Za-z] .* \R 
   (?= [A-Za-z] )
 | 
   (?<! \A )
   \G 
   [A-Za-z] .* \R 
)
\K
```

Comment: There is no need of `(?m)` as in  Notepad++ `^` and `$` always match start/end of a line. However, `\A` does not work in a usual way, but hopefully OP won't encounter edge cases.

Comment: That is a pretty cool pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew **_boost::regex(str,options)_**
One of the options for perl default is m-modifier is on.
For Perl style regex I use this as the default. It turns everything _Off_. Options are added via checkbox flags (for me).
`#define MOD    regex_constants::perl | boost::regex::no_mod_s | boost::regex::no_mod_m` 
If Mr. Notepad++ did the least, he left the default perl option m-modifier which is _On_.
As far as the BOS construct _`\A`_ the meaning can't change.
With `\A` https://regex101.com/r/IarSzF/1
Without `\A` https://regex101.com/r/DH6kdZ/1
Inline modifiers for portability.

Comment: @sln If you agree, can you vote to reopen it? To me the question "Now I want to add zero after consecutive lines that start with a character like following:" with an example seems pretty clean right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird  I don't see a open/close review link. Maybe I don't have the rep. I need 3k rep I think is why I don't see it. But since everything is _Closed_ or _Duplicate_ I doubt I will be giving many great answers anytime soon. It's the reason nobody uses SO anymore.

Comment: @sln Ow I forgot about that.

Comment: @Thefourthbird No problem. Check back in a year I may have enough rep by then if SO is still in business.

Comment: I just want to clarify @WiktorStribiżew that `\A` can be made inactive by boost::regex, and only by a Flags bit `match_not_bob` when doing a search. Its done by the developer when needing to set the starting offset into the buffer. Pretty sure Mr. Notepad++ don't do this. And doubtful he would take the time to learn how to do this incredibly difficult procedure..

Comment: The simplified version of this difficult procedure to void `\A` -> // Using BIDI 'base' (SitrStart)
// lets search see behind the  start BIDI.

Class has imbedded Regex Object. Method `findText( FRITRS frItrs, LPCTSTR lpcBuffer, int buflen, int nOffset )` 
executes the search based on the regex object member.
The start position is based on the passed in cursor position, the buffer _OFFSET_.
-----------------------
// if Offset > 0, - set the "Not Beginning of Buffer", aka \A
// Flags |= regex_constants::match_not_bob;
// Then REGEX_SEARCH( start, end, _m, Regex, Flags, SitrStart )

Answer (score 2):

If you also want to place a zero after the last item on the line:

Find what:

```
(?:\A[A-Z].*+|^(?:\h*|[^A-Z\r\n].*)\R[A-Z].*+)(?!\R[A-Z])(*SKIP)(*F)|^[A-Z].*
```

- `(?:` Non capture group for the 2 alternatives that we don't want to match

  - `\A[A-Z].*+` Match the first line if it starts with A-Z
  - `|` Or
  - `^(?:\h*|[^A-Z\r\n].*)` Either match an empty line or a lines that starts with a char different from A-Z or a newline
  - `\R[A-Z].*+` Match a newline and a line that starts with a char A-Z
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `(?!\R[A-Z])` Negative lookahead, assert that the next line does not start with A-Z
- `(*SKIP)(*F)|` Skip the match
- `^[A-Z].*` Match a line that starts with A-Z

Replace with the whole match denoted by `$0` followed by a newline and a zero:

```
$0\n0
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZsQoR/1)

Note to uncheck "Match case" for a case insensitive match:

[image]